# Find unique data types in table. SQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have the task of finding all unique data types in all the tables.

This is how I wrote the SQL query:

```
WITH UniqueColumnTypes AS 
(
    SELECT table_name, COUNT(DISTINCT data_type) AS unique_types
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
    GROUP BY table_name
)
SELECT table_name, unique_types
FROM UniqueColumnTypes;
```

For some reason, `CHAR(13)` and `CHAR(12)` are considered two different types.

I need them to be considered as the same data type.

I check the data types of the table with this code:

```
SELECT column_name, data_type
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'Book' AND table_schema = 'Stud';
```

I can see, that there are only 4 unique data types in the Book table. But the answer that the first code is giving me is 6 unique data types.

This is how this table is being created:

```
CREATE TABLE Stud.Book 
(
    ISBN      CHAR(13)    NOT NULL,
    Title     VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    Publisher CHAR(12)    NOT NULL,
    Year      SMALLINT    NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT LeidimoMetai CHECK (Year > 1900 AND Year < EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) + 1),
    Pages     SMALLINT    NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT PagesCount CHECK (Pages > 0 AND Pages < 2000),
    Price     DECIMAL(5, 2) 
        CONSTRAINT PriceSize CHECK (Price > 0 AND Price < 1000),
    PRIMARY KEY (ISBN)
);
```

With this, I can see, that there are only 4 unique data types in that table.

Comment: Why the WITH clause? (It's just a plain SELECT.)

Comment: What does `SELECT DISTINCT table_name, data_type FROM information_schema.columns WHERE    table_schema NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')` return for your table?

Comment: [Do Not use CHAR](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29). Char(12) means exactly 12 characters every time; Char(13) means exactly 13 characters every time. From that viewpoint they are different. Better just `varchar` or `text` as there is no benefit to using `char`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add

```
character_maximum_length
```

As the size is not part of the datatype

```
CREATE TABLE Book (
    ISBN           CHAR(13)    NOT NULL,
    Title          VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    Publisher      CHAR(12)    NOT NULL,
    Year           SMALLINT    NOT NULL CONSTRAINT LeidimoMetai 
                                         CHECK(Year > 1900 AND Year < EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) + 1),
    Pages          SMALLINT    NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PagesCount CHECK(Pages > 0 AND Pages < 2000),
    Price          DECIMAL(5,2) CONSTRAINT PriceSize CHECK(Price > 0 AND Price < 1000),
    PRIMARY KEY (ISBN)
);
SELECT column_name, data_type
FROM   information_schema.columns
WHERE  table_name = 'Book'
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

| column_name | data_type |
| --- | --- |

> ```
> SELECT 0
> ```

```
SELECT *
FROM   information_schema.columns
WHERE    table_schema NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
```

| table_catalog | table_schema | table_name | column_name | ordinal_position | column_default | is_nullable | data_type | character_maximum_length | character_octet_length | numeric_precision | numeric_precision_radix | numeric_scale | datetime_precision | interval_type | interval_precision | character_set_catalog | character_set_schema | character_set_name | collation_catalog | collation_schema | collation_name | domain_catalog | domain_schema | domain_name | udt_catalog | udt_schema | udt_name | scope_catalog | scope_schema | scope_name | maximum_cardinality | dtd_identifier | is_self_referencing | is_identity | identity_generation | identity_start | identity_increment | identity_maximum | identity_minimum | identity_cycle | is_generated | generation_expression | is_updatable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| postgres | public | book | year | 4 | *null* | NO | smallint | *null* | *null* | 16 | 2 | 0 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | postgres | pg_catalog | int2 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 4 | NO | NO | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | NO | NEVER | *null* | YES |
| postgres | public | book | pages | 5 | *null* | NO | smallint | *null* | *null* | 16 | 2 | 0 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | postgres | pg_catalog | int2 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 5 | NO | NO | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | NO | NEVER | *null* | YES |
| postgres | public | book | price | 6 | *null* | YES | numeric | *null* | *null* | 5 | 10 | 2 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | postgres | pg_catalog | numeric | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 6 | NO | NO | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | NO | NEVER | *null* | YES |
| postgres | public | book | isbn | 1 | *null* | NO | character | 13 | 52 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | postgres | pg_catalog | bpchar | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 1 | NO | NO | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | NO | NEVER | *null* | YES |
| postgres | public | book | title | 2 | *null* | NO | character varying | 32 | 128 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | postgres | pg_catalog | varchar | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 2 | NO | NO | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | NO | NEVER | *null* | YES |
| postgres | public | book | publisher | 3 | *null* | NO | character | 12 | 48 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | postgres | pg_catalog | bpchar | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 3 | NO | NO | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | NO | NEVER | *null* | YES |

> ```
> SELECT 6
> ```

```
SELECT column_name,     data_type,  character_maximum_length
FROM   information_schema.columns
WHERE    table_schema NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
```

| column_name | data_type | character_maximum_length |
| --- | --- | --- |
| year | smallint | *null* |
| pages | smallint | *null* |
| price | numeric | *null* |
| isbn | character | 13 |
| title | character varying | 32 |
| publisher | character | 12 |

> ```
> SELECT 6
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NztfH9iA)